# jQuery addClass to each element that has children with '.class'

Tags: jquery, each, addclass

I'm trying to add a Class to each anchor inside `#somecontainer` whose children have `.someclass`

For example.

```
<div id="container">
<a><span class="someclass"></span></a>
<a></a>
<a><span class="someclass">/span></a>
</div>
```

In the above code i want the first and third anchors to have a class '.anotherclass'
I tried this code but it doesn't seem to work

```
jQuery('#container a').each(function(){
jQuery(this).has('.someclass').addClass('anotherclass');
})
```

> **Update**: `.has()` returns a `boolean` and not jQuery object. That's why the
>   code  didn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect your problem stems from the fact that your HTML is malformed, i.e. you need to close your spans.

```
<div id="container">
<a><span class="someclass"></span></a>
<a></a>
<a><span class="someclass"></span></a>
</div>
```

Additionally, your code can be simplified a bit by using `:has` to select only anchors that contain an element matching your desired class name:

```
$('#container a:has(.someclass)').addClass('anotherclass');
```

i.e. "select all anchors that are descendants of an element with ID `container` and that have a descendant with class `someclass`"

As Jon has pointed out, an alternative is to use a basic selector, then filter the resulting collection using a custom function:

```
$('#container a').filter(function(){
    return $(this).has('.someclass').length > 0
}).each(function(){
    $(this).addClass('anotherclass');
});
```

The function needs to return `true` for any element that you want to retain, and `false` for any element you don't.

Comment: @Jon Do you mean for it to be used with a selector or a function?

Comment: @JanDvorak I suspect it is because his HTML is malformed (unclosed spans)

Comment: @Asad then I believe this will break under the same circumstances.

Comment: @Asad: With a function, mainly for when selectors won't cut it.

Comment: That code is just an example. The actual code doesn't have unclosed tags.

Comment: anyway, this code works like charm. still wondering why my code doesn't work.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, I've mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: @Jon I've added a mention of `filter` to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$('#container a .someclass').parents('a').addClass('anotherClass');
```

Basically we work our way right down to find the elements with the class 'someclass': `$('#container a .someclass')`, and then  from there work our way back up to the enclosing anchor: `.parents('a')`, which is where the class 'anotherclass' needs to be added.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('#container a .someclass').parent().addClass('anotherclass');​
```

Comment: this will add the class to the `span`. This is not the desire.